# How to determine if internal storage is full?

Tags: android, storage

I am making an android app which saves a 2MB `.txt` file in the internal storage. How can I know if the internal storage is full, and thus save the file to the external storage?

Comment: check exception if not enough space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the quick search I found the following way. You can get it from [StatFs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html#getAvailableBlocks%28%29) class. This class is used to Retrieve overall information about the space on a filesystem.

```
public int FreeMemory()
{
    StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    int Free  = (statFs.getAvailableBlocks() * statFs.getBlockSize()) / 1048576;
    return Free;
}
```

Also you can find by the following way

```
File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
long availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocks();
return Formatter.formatFileSize(this, availableBlocks * blockSize);
```

You can get more detail from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163045/android-how-to-check-availability-of-space-on-external-storage/8826427#8826427) and [here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595334/android-get-free-space-on-internal-memory/4595449#4595449).

I hope this will help you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Pleae check the following code (I have copied it in this site but I do not remember where exactly it is)

```
public static boolean externalMemoryAvailable() {
    return android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
}

public static String getAvailableInternalMemorySize() {
    File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
    long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
    long availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocks();
    return formatSize(availableBlocks * blockSize);
}

public static String getTotalInternalMemorySize() {
    File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
    long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
    long totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCount();
    return formatSize(totalBlocks * blockSize);
}

public static String getAvailableExternalMemorySize() {
    if (externalMemoryAvailable()) {
        File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
        long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
        long availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocks();
        return formatSize(availableBlocks * blockSize);
    } else {
        return ERROR;
    }
}

public static String getTotalExternalMemorySize() {
    if (externalMemoryAvailable()) {
        File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
        long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
        long totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCount();
        return formatSize(totalBlocks * blockSize);
    } else {
        return ERROR;
    }
}

public static String formatSize(long size) {
    String suffix = null;

    if (size >= 1024) {
        suffix = "KB";
        size /= 1024;
        if (size >= 1024) {
            suffix = "MB";
            size /= 1024;
        }
    }

    StringBuilder resultBuffer = new StringBuilder(Long.toString(size));

    int commaOffset = resultBuffer.length() - 3;
    while (commaOffset > 0) {
        resultBuffer.insert(commaOffset, ',');
        commaOffset -= 3;
    }

    if (suffix != null) resultBuffer.append(suffix);
    return resultBuffer.toString();
}
```

wish to help you.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `float freeSpace = DeviceMemory.getInternalFreeSpace();`  ?